# "1 warning generated" after installing psycopg2 from pip3, django and postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm learning django and I'm trying to use postgresql, and I need to install psycopg2 module.

When I `sudo pip install psycopg2` I get this:

```
The directory '/Users/hello/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/hello/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting psycopg2
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz (371kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 372kB 381kB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psycopg2
  Stored in directory: /Users/hello/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/e2/9a/5e/7b620848bbc7cfb9084aafea077be11618c2b5067bd532f329
Successfully built psycopg2
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.6.1
```

Then when I did `sudo pip3 install psycopg2`

I get more messages, but I noticed this message:

```
In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:81:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33:
./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
1 warning generated.
In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:81:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33:
./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
1 warning generated.
```

And I think this gets repeated... but in the end, it says `Successfully installed psycopg2-2.6.1`

Why do I get a bunch of messages and that error? Is that normal?

Thanks

Comment: This is harmless warning about unused function likely used to print out debug messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a warning message from C compiler. C compiler is invoked to build native Python extension needed for the library. Warning messages are usually platform and compiler dependent. You can usually safely ignore them if you are not debugging or diagnosing a particular problem.